# Seeking Opinion:Denormalising Fact and Dim tables to improve performance of SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting, data-warehouse

We seem to have bit of a debate on a discussion point in our team. 
We are working on a Data Warehouse in the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 platform. We have followed the Kimball Architecture to build this Data Warehouse.

**Issue:**

A reporting solution (built on SSRS), which sources data from this Warehouse, has significant performance issues when sourcing data from fact and dim tables. Some of our team members suggest that we extract data from facts and dims into a new set of tables using SSIS packages. This would mean we denormalise these tables into ‘Snapshot’ tables.  In this way the we would not need to join these tables to create data sets within the reports. Data could be read out of these tables directly.

I do have my own worries about this; inconsistencies, maintenance of different data structures, duplication of data etc to name a few.

**Question:**

Would you consider creating snapshot tables (by denormalising facts and dim tables) for reporting tables a right approach?

Would like to hear your thoughts on this.

Cheers
Nithin

Comment: I'd like to have a crack at a considered answer to this and suggest alternatives if I can think of any. But first can you explain more about the facts and dims in question, and perhaps give an example (even if only illustrative) of the differences. In particular I'd like to find out what you mean by denormalising facts and dim tables. Dims are normally denormalised anyway, and facts are either transactional, snapshots or accumulating snapshots. Are you talking about making snapshots in addition to your transactional facts? Also, do you have access to SSAS?

Comment: Have you run into trouble powering drop downs etc (which prefer a distinct list of values over a source column), or is it bigger than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with snapshot tables.  The two most important aspects of a data warehouse are:

1. The data is correct.
2. The data is useful.

If your users are unable to extract the totals they require, in a reasonable timescale, they won't use the warehouse.

My own solution includes 3 snapshot tables.  Like you, I was worried about inconsistencies.  To address this we built an automated checking process.  This sub-system executes a series of queries, stored on a network drive, once an hour.  Any records returned by the queries are considered a fail.  Fails are reported and immediately investigated by my ETL team.  This sub-system ensures the snapshots and underlying facts are always aligned and consistent with each other.  Drift is prevented.

That said, additional tables equals additional complexity.  And that requires more time/effort to manage.  Before introducing another layer to your warehouse, you should investigate why these queries are underperforming.  If joins are to blame:

1. Are you using an inappropriate data type, for your P/F keys?
2. Are the FKeys indexed (some RDBMS do this by default, others do not)?
3. Have you looked at the execution plans, for the offending queries?
4. Is the join really to blame, or is it a filter applied to the dim table?

Comment: Thank you... I believe the team still needs to answer some of the questions that we raised and the points you raised aligns well with the ones which we have asked...your thoughts just reaffirmed that we were in the right track..Cheers Nithin

Answer (score 1):

for raw cube performance my advice would be to always try to denormalize your tables and have one fact table and one table for each dimension (star schema).
If you are unsure if it will actually help you could start creating materialized views. These are kind of the best of both worlds, on the long run you should alter your etl.
In my previous job we only had flattened tables which worked quite well. Currenly we have a normalized schema but flatten it in the last step.

Comment: The questioner said they already used Kimball to build the data warehouse, which would be situation you describe, so am assuming they mean something else!

Comment: After rereading the post I am still not sure. Maybe op will clarify his question as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Rich/Kaylon

This is just an example: There is a Fact_Sales, with dims Dim_Location and Dim_Product and Dim_Date. Ideally if I was reporting sales measures, I would write a query on top of the Fact table and then join to the Dim_Location and Dim_Product and Dim_Date based on the keys. The result of the query would be reported through a report.

Some team members  want the tables joined in a query, which should be then fed through an ETL package , into an aggregated table.  Reports run on top of this table would render better performance. Is this a good practice??

Cheers
Nithin